# pointer to an array of pointer to functions

Tags: c, pointers

I would like f to point to an array of f_pointer_type. So what did i miss here ? I'm getting an error 'lvalue required as left operand of assignment'. What does it mean ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef char* (*f_pointer_type)();
char * retHello()
{
    return "hello";
}
int main()
{
    char (* ( *f())[])(); //Declare f to be a pointer to an array of pointers to function that gets nothing and return a char.
    f_pointer_type funcs[3]; //an array of pointers to function that gets nothing and returns a pointer to char
    f = &funcs; //ERROR : lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use typedef in f variable definition? f_pointer_type** f; -

Comment: I guess f is interpreted as some crazy function forward declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read about the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) you will see that `f` is actually a function returning a pointer to an array of pointers to functions returning `char*`. In other words it's a function prototype and not a variable declaration.

Try this instead:

```
f_pointer_type (*f)[];
```

Answer (score 1):

An array of function pointers is written as `char* (*f[])()`. You have the parenthesis wrong.

Though it is of course better to always use typedef as in the `f_pointer_type funcs[3]` example.

Answer (score 1):

You define `f` as a `function pointer.` `f` is pointer to a function who has `void params` and `return char *`